# Crosstool-ng and dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, armv6, crosstool-ng, wiringpi

How do I use a custom dynamic library (wiringPi in my case) with a ARMv6 C++ compiler that was created with crosstool-ng?
I built wiringPi then added -lwiringPi to the linker options, and this works fine using g++ but does not when using the new ARMv6 C++ compiler.

Error is: `ld: cannot find -lwiringPi`

Given that the crosstool compiler seems to have a structure of its own, maybe I have to build the library somewhere inside the ARMv6 C++ compiler files?

Comment: Where is your compiler located and where did you install your library?

Comment: ARMv6 compiler located in ~/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/, the library is in /usr/local/lib. I installed the compiler following this tutorial: [tuto](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/426)

Comment: So your compiler won't find the library, since /usr/local/lib is location for your OS, and the compiler probably will try to find it under ~/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabin/somedirnameidontremember/lib. Use `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc --print-search-dirs` or `--print-sysroot` to get the hint where you should install your lib.

Comment: Making progress! I copied my *.so files in the [...]/sysroot/lib/ folder indicated by --print-sysroot. Now I get the following output : 

`[...]libwiringPi.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized`
Using the library files on my raspberry pi did not help, the library is still of unrecognized format...

Comment: Check with `file` command what file type `libwiringPi.so` really is. Could be, you compiled the library for your native architecture (e.g. i386 or x86_64) and try to use it for armv6.

Comment: If I take a random library in that same folder I get:
`ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.12.43, not stripped`
My files, taken from the raspberry pi build:
`ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=cbd69abfafee95a462e64a34c3b862a5023190d4, not stripped`
How can I build my library "for GNU/Linux 3.12.43"? Maybe using crosstools-ng again?

Comment: So, if your libwiringPi.so is built form ARM EABI5 (which is good), make sure that for compiling your project you use arm g++ compiler... and arm linker (so you don't use `/usr/bin/ld`, but `~/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknow-linux-gnueabi-ld`).

Comment: Solved!! First, thanks a lot for your help! It made me aware of a lot of things I absolutely did not know. 
In addition to using the right linker as you just said, there was one more critical step. I had used crosstool-ng to create a soft float compiler, which is apparently the default with my ubuntu, but the Raspberry Pi is a hard float system! Therefore I had to create a new hard float ARM compiler. Lastly, custom libraries have to go in [...]/sysroot/usr/lib, and nowhere else! Thanks again!